# Eliminar registros repetidos de una tabla en MySQL

Tags: mysql

He logrado hacer para que me muestre cuantos datos tengo repetidos pero ahora quiero hacer una consulta para eliminar los registros que tengan 5 datos repetidos: id_alumno, id_curso, semestre notafinal y id_seccion.

```
select  count(*),
            uni_notas.id_alumno,
            uni_notas.id_curso,
            asd_personas.nombre,
            uni_notas.notafinal,`introducir el código aquí`
            uni_secciones.codigo,
            uni_cursos.codigo,
            uni_cursos.nombre,
            uni_notas.semestre
from uni_notas 
          inner join uni_cursos
                on uni_cursos.id = uni_notas.id_curso
          inner join uni_alumnos 
                on uni_notas.id_alumno = uni_alumnos.id
          inner join asd_personas
                on asd_personas.id = uni_alumnos.id_persona
          inner join uni_secciones 
                on uni_secciones.id = uni_notas.id_seccion
where uni_cursos.codigo in (select uni_cursos.codigo from uni_cursos where uni_cursos.codigo LIKE '%35%')
          group by id_alumno, id_curso, notafinal, semestre, id_seccion
                having count(1)>1
```

El script para crear la tabla original es:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS uni_notas ( 
    id int(11) NOT NULL
  , id_curso int(11) DEFAULT NULL
  , id_seccion int(11) DEFAULT NULL
  , id_alumno int(11) DEFAULT NULL
  , creditos decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL
  , semestre char(6) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
  , asistencia int(3) DEFAULT NULL
  , zona int(3) DEFAULT NULL
  , siglas char(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
  , exfinal int(3) DEFAULT NULL
  , notafinal int(3) DEFAULT NULL
  , recupera int(3) DEFAULT NULL
  , tipo char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
  , estado int(1) DEFAULT '1' 
)
```

Comment: Cuando hablas de elminar, quieres eliminar todos o simplemente quieres eliminar 4 y dejar uno de ellos?

Comment: gracias @JoseJavierSegura si quiero eliminar todos los registros que esten duplicados en los que se encuentre el id_curso, id_alumno, semestre y notafinal.

Comment: Presumo que te refieres a eliminar registros de la tabla **uni_notas**. Podrías agregar la estructura de la misma a la tabla para entender mejor el problema y poder brindarte una mejor respuesta.

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `uni_notas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_curso` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_seccion` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_alumno` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creditos` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `semestre` char(6) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `asistencia` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zona` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `siglas` char(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `exfinal` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notafinal` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `recupera` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `estado` int(1) DEFAULT '1'
)

Comment: @Cris, lo que has agregado como comentario no se entiende, lo que se espera que hagas es editar tu pregunta y añadir la información a ella. En este caso lo haré yo por ti.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si estás utilizando **MySQL 5.7.3** o inferior y no tienes preferencias sobre que registros de **uni_notas** repetidos quedarte, una posibilidad es crear un **índice único** usando la extensión **IGNORE** sobre los campos que mencionas.

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `uni_notas`   
ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`id_alumno`, `id_curso`, `semestre`, `notafinal` y `id_seccion`);
```

Nuevamente, esta solución vale sí tienes la versión de MySQL adecuada (no por nada se ha removido la extensión) y no te importa con que duplicado quedarte.

Si tienes algún criterio para quedarte con uno u otro registro, entonces la solución a tu problema viene por algo más elaborado. Y lo primero que deberías indicar es cuál sería dicho criterio.

Comment: Gracias me sirvió mucho! :)

Comment: Hay otra manera muy util para eso, ayer estuve investigando: 

delete n1 from uni_notas n1, uni_notas n2 where n1.id < n2.id 
  and n1.id_alumno = n2.id_alumno 
  and n1.id_curso = n2.id_curso 
  and n1.notafinal = n2.notafinal 
  and n1.semestre = n2.semestre 
  and n1.id_seccion = n2.id_seccion

Answer (score 0):

En este caso, yo creo que lo mejor que puedes hacer es multiplicar la tabla por si misma en función de los 5 campos que quieres, y eliminar todos los ids distintos a los seleccionados en la tabla de la izquierda del producto cartesiano.

```
    DELETE FROM uni_notas U1 JOIN uni_notas U2 ON 
     (
       U1.id_alumno = U2.id_alumno AND 
       U1.id_curso = U2.id_curso AND 
       ...
     ) WHERE U2.id <> U1.id
```

En según que versiones de MySQL te puede dar error al seleccionar y borrar de la misma tabla, si es tu caso, crea una tabla temporal con los ids de las notas que haya que borrar y luego ejecuta un:

```
DELETE FROM uni_notas WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM temp_table)
```